# Can bipartite graphs have isolated vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Can a bipartite graph have some isolated vertices?

Comment: It can have nothing else but isolated vertices.

Comment: the graph $G=(\{v\},\emptyset)$ is bipartite

Comment: In this case, isolated vertices will be members for which part? It seams such graph has more than two parts

Comment: You can put it in whatever part you like as it won't be connected to any member within the part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bipartite graph need not have *exactly* two *unique* parts. The condition is that you should be able to split it up into two parts such that the only edges in the graph go between the two parts and not within. The two parts need not have any edges between them at all, so in particular vertices can be isolated. The isolated vertices can go in either part.

Comment: In your profile bio, it says that if we want to work with you academically, we should comment on one of your posts..... My email is gsaxena888....<and the rest is the standard gmaaiil suffix etc.). I'd love to chat briefly over email.